# Fixed points of Banach.

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $S,T : M \hookleftarrow$.

***By definition. Let $M$ a set. A fixed point of an application $A:M\hookleftarrow$ is an element $\xi \in M$ satisfying $A(\xi)=\xi$.***

If $TS=ST$ (commute), then what relation exists between the fixed points of $ S $ and $ T $?.

Comment: What is $M$? Are $S$ and $T$ linear/continuous? Please provide some context.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking... If $S(x) = x$, then $S(T(x)) = TS(x) = T(x)$. So the set of fixed points of $S$ is invariant under $T$, and vice versa. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @ridias: $S$ y $T$ are applications.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee: From my point of view, it is to show an analysis.

Comment: I think I am still not fully following your question. As I explained in my previous comment, if $x$ is a fixed point of $S$, then $T(x)$ is also a fixed point of $S$. But except that, I see no other obvious relations between fixed points of $S$ and those of $T$... Also, although not related to the question, I guess the term 'application' is not famous among English users. (Either 'map' or 'function' is more widely used.)